# How to enable gaze only for mobile VR mode

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

How to enable the **gaze** only for the **mobile VR mode** this the code that I tried but the gaze gets enabled mobile hand held mode also I do no that how to enabled gaze only for mobile VR please share some related snippets it'll be very helpful to me

Thanks in advance

```js
var cursorEl = document.querySelector('a-cursor');
             if (!AFRAME.utils.device.isMobile()) {
             cursorEl.parentEl.removeChild(cursorEl.src);
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `.src`.

`cursorEl.parentEl.removeChild(cursorEl);`

Comment: No while removing src also it's working on mobile hand held mode.I need to set the cursor  visible="true" or "false"?